# When I change the values of an object to a number from text, I get an error nan, in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I have a problem turning an object with string values into values of a number.

For example this is the object I have:

```
 { _redis: '3', _mysql: '2', _nodejs: '5', _mongo: '4', _python: '3' }
```

I want to get the object with numbers and not strings like this:

```
 { _redis: 3, _mysql: 2, _nodejs: 5, _mongo: 4, _python: 3 }
```

This is the function I did, but it does not work for me, I do not understand why.

```js
function convertObjectWithStrToNumber (engineerDetails) {
  let engineerDetailsWithNumbers = {};

  engineerDetailsWithNumbers = Object.keys(engineerDetails).map(([key, value]) => ([key, Number(value)]));

  return engineerDetailsWithNumbers;
  }
  
  let engineer = { _redis: '3', _mysql: '2', _nodejs: '5', _mongo: '4', _python: '3' };
  
  console.log(convertObjectWithStrToNumber(engineer));
```

When I run the function I get this error:

```
 [
    [ '_', NaN ],
    [ '_', NaN ],
    [ '_', NaN ],
    [ '_', NaN ],
    [ '_', NaN ]
  ]
```

I do not understand where the problem is, I turned the object into an array, and after that I went through all the members, and instead of string values I gave them values of a number.

Comment: `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function convertObjectWithStrToNumber (engineerDetails) {
  const engineerDetailsWithNumbers = {} 
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(engineerDetails)) {
    engineerDetailsWithNumbers[key] = Number(value)
  }

  return engineerDetailsWithNumbers;
}
  
let engineer = { _redis: '3', _mysql: '2', _nodejs: '5', _mongo: '4', _python: '3' };
  
console.log(convertObjectWithStrToNumber(engineer));
```

I think your lookup was wrong (value)

Answer (score 7):

`Object.keys` gives you an array of **keys**. Destructuring `[key, value]` from a key - a string - won't give you the key and the value, but the first character and the second character.

Use `Object.entries` instead, and turn the array of mapped entries back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
function convertObjectWithStrToNumber(engineerDetails) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(engineerDetails).map(
      ([key, value]) => [key, Number(value)]
    )
  );
}
let engineer = {
  _redis: '3',
  _mysql: '2',
  _nodejs: '5',
  _mongo: '4',
  _python: '3'
};

console.log(convertObjectWithStrToNumber(engineer));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I get an object with "" around its properties, how can I delete it?

Comment: The keys do not contain `'`s, those are just the visual delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to make your own function?  You can use the `parseInt();` function to do this much easier.  `parseInt();` requires the string to be parsed, and an optional parameter that specifies which number system will be used.